# performance issues with passing in a method as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

i have a need to invoke some methods asynchrounously. On startup, the app does some work on initializing a few things but I don't want the UI to be held up. So, this function is performed in a separate thread using Threadpool queueitem method.

I was thinking to have a few methods similar to below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoAsyncOperation(new Func<string, int>(TestMethod), "test");
}

private int TestMethod(string p)
{
    return 0;
}

public bool DoAsyncOperation(Delegate asyncMethod, params object[] args)
{
    return ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate {asyncMethod.DynamicInvoke(args);});
}
```

so that in future other methods can also be run async if needed and its all in one place. If I have to change logic for the threading, I can do it in a single method.

Is there any performance issues with this approach, passing in the method dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always: "*Profile Profile Profile*"! That said, in this case I'd be fairly sure to say:

No not at all at this scale, it doesn't matter:

The actual time spent loading the page or even managing the Queue far outweighs the invocation overhead of a delegate (even if it uses DynamicInvoke under the hood)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you suggest some ways I can profile this, just to learn.

Comment: @AlexJ: I'd suggest [MiniProfiler for ASP.Net (and ASP.Net MVC)](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) or pick any one of the general purpose [.NET Profiler tools from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)